# Is it possible to change other attributes of configurable product other than price?

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, custom-options

I am new to magento, so far I am looking at tutorials on the video, my understanding is that configurable product is set of several simple products.

> If so, can attributes be changed when specific options is selected?

In practice:

Let's say there is T-Shirt configurable product

Blue T-shirt small size has attribute: Pocket count: 3
Red T-Shirt large size has attribute: Pocket count: none

so when blue color option and small size option is selected, it displays pocket count 3

> Is that achievable? and would that 2 kind of products can be
>   comparable to each other?

Thanks